# ruby rake with rails missing constant with production but works in development environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, jruby, rake-task

I have a rake task that runs ok in the dev env, but not in prod.

```
task :sample_test_quote => :environment do

  QuoterTester.test

end
```

QuoterTester is a model class with a class method test.

Running the task under dev works fine, like this:

```
rake sample_test_quote
```

Whereas under prod, I get this:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake sample_test_quote --trace
** Invoke sample_test_quote (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sample_test_quote
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant QuoterTester
org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2590:in `const_missing'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
org/jruby/RubyMethod.java:133:in `call'
/Users/kimptoc/Documents/ruby/ecom/ecom1/lib/tasks/sample_test_quote.rake:3:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063:in `load'
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5@p-ecom1-rails311/bin/rake:19:in `(root)'
Tasks: TOP => sample_test_quote
```

I am using JRuby 1.6.5, with mysql - the prod and dev database.yml are pretty much the same settings.  Also using a Gemfile - see below.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056894/rails-production-env-object-is-not-missing-constant), I am guessing its a problem with one of classes in the project.

So, any tips on how to track down which class?

Strangely, rails server/console both work in prod env - I'd have expected them to fail too.

TIA, Chris

Here is the Gemfile I am using

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

if defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)
  #jruby gems
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
  #gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', :git => "https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter.git"
  #gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
  #gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter', :path => '../../libs/activerecord-jdbc-adapter.kimptoc'
  #gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter',:git => "https://github.com/kimptoc/activerecord-jdbc-adapter.git"
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter',:git => "https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter.git"
  gem "jruby-openssl"
else
  #non jruby gems
  gem 'mysql'
end

gem "letter_opener", :group => :development



gem "mechanize", "1.0.0"

gem "nokogiri","1.4.6"

gem "roo"
gem "rubyzip"

gem "parallel"


gem "savon", "=0.7.9"


group :development, :test do
  gem "rcov"
  gem "pry"
end

gem "fastercsv"

gem "xml-simple"

gem "rabl"

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'

gem 'newrelic_rpm'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', " ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', " ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "acts_as_executor", :git => "https://github.com/philostler/acts_as_executor.git"

gem 'rufus-scheduler'
```

And here are the actual gems:

```
actionmailer (3.1.1)
actionpack (3.1.1)
activemodel (3.1.1)
activerecord (3.1.1)
activeresource (3.1.1)
activesupport (3.1.1)
addressable (2.2.6)
arel (2.2.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1 java)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0146.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
coderay (0.9.8)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
crack (0.3.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.9)
fastercsv (1.5.4)
google-spreadsheet-ruby (0.1.5)
hike (1.2.1)
hoe (2.12.3)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.16)
jruby-launcher (1.0.9 java)
jruby-openssl (0.7.4)
json (1.6.1 java)
launchy (2.0.5)
letter_opener (0.0.2)
mail (2.3.0)
mechanize (1.0.0)
method_source (0.6.6)
mime-types (1.17.1, 1.16)
multi_json (1.0.3)
newrelic_rpm (3.2.0)
nokogiri (1.4.6 java)
oauth (0.4.5)
parallel (0.5.9)
polyglot (0.3.2)
pry (0.9.6.2 java)
rabl (0.5.0, 0.3.0)
rack (1.3.5, 1.3.4)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.1)
railties (3.1.1)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
rcov (0.9.11 java)
rdoc (3.11, 3.10)
roo (1.9.5)
ruby-ole (1.2.11.2)
ruby_parser (2.0.6)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
rufus-scheduler (2.0.12)
sass (3.1.10)
sass-rails (3.1.4)
savon (0.7.9)
sexp_processor (3.0.7)
slop (2.1.0)
spoon (0.0.1)
spreadsheet (0.6.5.9)
sprockets (2.0.3, 2.0.2)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.30)
uglifier (1.0.4, 1.0.3)
weakling (0.0.4 java)
xml-simple (1.1.1)
```

Comment: Can you show the rake task and the full error output?

Comment: Thanks Douglas - it was a bit short on details :)

Comment: do you have the gem set in the production section of your gemfile?

Comment: Hi Andrei - are you thinking the problem might be due to a gem being marked as dev only. I dont think I am doing anything different in this code compared to the main app and thus it should be using the same gems. But maybe rake is stricter on this... I will review the gems

Comment: He means, are you using a `Gemfile` and have added this to your `group :development` block?

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks - yes, using a Gemfile - not sure what you mean about adding to the group :development block - can you specify rake tasks are only for specific environments?  Anyway, included the Gemfile and gem list in question now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a fairly common issue when Rake tasks are run in production mode if `config.threadsafe!` is enabled, which it should be for JRuby apps.

A possible fix is to edit your environment so that `config.threadsafe!` is disabled only when you are running a Rake task (You can make up your own environment variable for this purpose).

Comment: Many Thanks, sounds good - will give it a go tonight, when I get home

Comment: That was it - I've now wrapped the config setting with "if defined?(Rails::Server)" and it works fine with Rake.

Comment: Glad to hear it! It's also great to share the JRuby love :-)

Comment: This also fixed it for me, but do you know what's the cause of the error?

Comment: @ser1681360 Yeah, I think it's because Rake (as it is today) depends upon a lot of shared state where class definitions may be loaded in one thread, but later used in another. Because Rake hasn't been developed to be threadsafe, you see errors like this in threadsafe mode under JRuby. You don't see this issue much in Rails anymore because a great deal of work has been put into making Rails more threadsafe over the last couple of years.

Comment: hopefully fixed in Rails 4.0 https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2274#issuecomment-7934529

Comment: @ChrisKimpton be careful with `Rails::Server` check. This is not defined when using Unicorn in example.