# Validating Non-Database Model with array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So here is my non-database model.

```
class UserApplication::CoApplicant

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  attr_accessor :applicant, :first_name, :last_name, :email



  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

I am looking to pass in an array of objects, that look something like this.

```
"applicant"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"blank@gmail.com", "last_name"=>"Jackson", "first_name"=>"Shaun"}, "1"=>{"email"=>"blank2@gmail.com", "last_name"=>"Davis", "first_name"=>"Dave"}}
```

The issue I am having is coming up with a way to validate each object. These values are

coming from a dynamically generated table, that can range from 1 - 10 rows.

"0" and "1" - Represents the table row. And I am looking to validate each set

of attributes { email, first_name, last_name}.

I have never had to do this type of validation before, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to instantiate each of your instances and then validate them. This should be as simple as creating them based on your source array:

```
applicant_data = applicants['applicant']
applicant_data.each do |id, attributes|
  applicant = applicant.new(attributes)
  applicant.valid?
end
```

You also have a mistake in your assignment where you're calling the `"#{name}"` method, not the `#{name}=` method:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  attributes.each do |name, value|
    send("#{name}=", value)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that was very helpful.  Not sure why I was having such a hard time with this, but you cleared it right up.

Comment: I ran into this issue before on a few of my solutions, as well as the one that you have provided.                                                                                                                               "UserApplication is not missing constant Applicant!"  From what I read from other sources, this is a rails < 3.1 bug?  Have you experienced this, or know anything about it?

Comment: Have a look around here: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056894/rails-production-env-object-is-not-missing-constant)